# problema para instalar nest2d

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de instalar esta libreria pero  obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error

```
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
    CMake Error at C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/nest2D-master/Library/share/cmake- 
    3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
      Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)
     Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/nest2D-master/Library/share/cmake- 
      3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/nest2D-master/Library/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2177 
     (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/jorda/Desktop/New folder (5)/nest2D-master/build/temp.win-amd64- 
    3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 71, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 
    153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", 
      line 67, in run
        self.do_egg_install()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", 
      line 109, in do_egg_install
        self.run_command('bdist_egg')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site- 
      packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 167, in run
        cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site- 
      packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 153, in call_command
        self.run_command(cmdname)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\site- 
       packages\setuptools\command\install_lib.py", line 11, in run
        self.build()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\command\install_lib.py", line 107, 
      in build
        self.run_command('build_ext')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setup.py", line 42, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "setup.py", line 68, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=self.build_temp, env=env)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nest2D-master\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\jorda\\Desktop\\New folder (5)\\nest2D- 
     master', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\jorda\\Desktop\\New folder (5
    )\\nest2D-master\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '- 
    DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nest2D-master\\python.exe', '- 
    DRP_ENABLE_DOWNLOADING=on', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DI
    RECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\jorda\\Desktop\\New folder (5)\\nest2D-master\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', 
    '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Por favor puedes poner como estás tratand de instalar la librería, así como el sistema operativo, la versión de Python, etc. Por otro lado se ve que es una librería con poco soporte por lo que puede que tenga fallos.

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar. pip install nest2D, w10 python 3.8

Comment: @JordanMartinez Por favor evita señalar tu frustración o cosas similares ya que son solo ruido, en vez de ello deberias señalar más información de tu entorno como una edición y no solo como un comentario

Comment: @JordanMartinez Parece que nest2D no provee los binarios necesarios por lo que esta intentando compilarlo pero necesita un ingrediente: la librería boost que parece que no tienes instalado

Comment: muchas gracias @eyllanesc voy tomar los consejos